# Can the HTML5 Canvas take in and use XML data similar to Actionscript?

Tags: xml, html, canvas

I've had a search around and i don't know if i've looked in the wrong places, but i couldn't find a definitive answer. I'm looking to reproduce a Flash/Actionscript program that intakes XML data in the canvas, and was wondering firstly how possible this is, and secondly if there are any reliable resources to read up on around the subject.

To be more specific...

A program that reads in numeric values and simply displays them on a screen, such as rugby scores.

Comment: please, ask a more specific question. For all we know you could be looking for a way to write a program that displays the number of tags in a given XML file using a Tahoma font.

Comment: That would tell me that yes it is possible to read XML data, so erm, could've said that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to read XML data. It is also possible to draw on canvas. You could write a program that combines both possibilities into one solution. If your question is to be interpreted as: "Does Javascript work and offer APIs comparable to those of ActionScript", then the answer is a definite yes.

The resources are immensely broad. Just learn Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.  HTML5 Canvas is just an API.  You would use JavaScript to retrieve the XML (with XMLHttpRequest), parse it and then display it to the screen.  Display could be handled either by drawing to a canvas or adding text nodes to a web page.